# tweepy error response status code 400

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to write a simple twitter bot using python and tweepy. The code is as follows:

```
import tweepy
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status('hi')
```

I get the following error:

```
TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400
```

I would like some info on how to avoid this error

Comment: -  Check internet connectivity - Check your credentials

Comment: @Anmol_uppal I believe this is a bug in the latest lease of Tweepy. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a bug that emerged in the 3.2.0 release of Tweepy. See [this issue opened on GitHub](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/554). In that issue, TylerGlaiel notes that api.update_status fails if called thus:

```
api.update_status('Test')
```

But works if called like so:

```
api.update_status(status='Test')
```

I have also found this works. I imagine a fix will be out before long.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working now. Also, can you point me to some tutorial on how to make a bot that replies to specific words in someone's tweet?

Comment: @HassanSalman I don't know of a tutorial on this off hand. You could post this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence: `api.update_status(status='Test')` let you know if your API Key and Token is working well. So, if you see:

> TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400

Possibly means that you need to regenerate your credentiales for any reason. Regenerate your API Key, API Secret Key and your Tokens and will work.